# ServiceConnectionLeaked with youtube api

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

First of all, I've read this problem in some threads here and I know that could be fix replacing the getActivity() with the application context. All this answers are from some years ago, and now I think that is not supportes the application context, because I get an error when I put the application context and in the methods of the library I can't find any method to can put the application context.

When I create tye YoutubeStandalonePlayer I'm doing this:

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(getActivity(), getResources().getString(google_maps_key), mPublication.getYoutubeCode());
```

if I try to put the app context I get an error because I'm passing an app context and not the activity, that is the property that the method is waiting for.

```
 Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(ApplicationConfig.getAppContext(), getResources().getString(google_maps_key), mPublication.getYoutubeCode());
```

Then, my question is... how can I fix the problem of ServiceConnectionLeaked using the YouTubeStandalonePlayer:

```
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.buzinger.loycus.activity.HomeActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@cbfec60 that was originally bound here
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution that I've found in this website(https://androidadagnitio.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/activity-has-leaked-serviceconnection-com-google-android-youtube-player-internal-re391c339-that-was-originally-bound-here-error-solution/)

You need to add this line to avoid the ServiceConnectionLeaked with youtube api.

```
 youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
```

All the code:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder,final int position) {

        holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videos.get(position));
          //here is the magic to solve the logcat error 
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                        youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                //write something for failure
            }
        });
    }
```